# Write pandas dataframe to Azure Blob - Python sdk

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-python

I am trying to upload a dataframe to blob as csv.

Following is my code :

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient
sas_url = "https://XXX.blob.core.windows.net/YYYY?sp=r&st=2021-04-26T16:21:37Z&se=2021-04-27T00:21:37Z&spr=" \
          "https&sv=2020-02-10&sr=c&sig=lJxx45wdBT%2F5ZJQwPxxxxxxxxx0%3D"
blob_client = BlobClient.from_blob_url(sas_url)
print (blob_client)
blob_client.upload_blob(data=df1.to_csv(index=False))
```

The error is face is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xxx\xxx\PycharmProjects\DIF\venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3437, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-40ff66c54682>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/xxx/xxx/PycharmProjects/DIF/venv/Scripts/SF_ADLS.py', wdir='C:/xxx/xxx/PycharmProjects/DIF/venv/Scripts')
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.4\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.4\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/xxx/xxx/PycharmProjects/DIF/venv/Scripts/SF_ADLS.py", line 99, in <module>
    blob_client = BlobClient.from_blob_url(sas_url)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\DIF\venv\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\_blob_client.py", line 246, in from_blob_url
    container_name, blob_name = unquote(path_blob[-2]), unquote(path_blob[-1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Second Approach:
Generated the SAS token thru python code :

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, generate_account_sas, ResourceTypes, AccountSasPermissions
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\ccc\ccc\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2020.1\scratches\sf_metadata.csv')
sas_token = generate_account_sas(
    account_name="acct",
    account_key="so1uwLUIrFluxxxxxx38MGpL5XKU/yFNIkiyyyyitQPrWQ==",
    resource_types=ResourceTypes(service=True),
    permission=AccountSasPermissions(read=True,write=True,delete=True,add=True,create=True,update=True),
    expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1)
)

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url="https://acct.blob.core.windows.net", credential=sas_token)
print (sas_token)
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client('testfs1', 'one', snapshot=None)
blob_client.upload_blob(data=df1.to_csv(index=False))
```

Error I face :

```
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this resource type.
RequestId:03e71e74-601e-0022-2f25-3be77a000000
Time:2021-04-27T05:24:51.5741680Z
ErrorCode:AuthorizationResourceTypeMismatch
Error:None
```

Can you tell me what changes I have to do in my code.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the definition of the official document, your `sas_url` is wrong, and you are missing `blob-name`:

```
https://<account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>/<blob-name>?<sas-token>
```

You can refer to this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#examples).

And you'd better generate `SAS Token` here:

[image]

If the SAS Token is generated here, an authentication failure error may occur:

[image]

======================**update**===================

Please change

```
resource_types=ResourceTypes(service=True)
```

to

```
resource_types=ResourceTypes(object=True)
```

Comment: I tried the method you prescribed in the first screenshot. I used Blob service SAS URL. It was not having container and blob name. Facing the same error.

Comment: @Madhanlal. If you use `sas_url` to create `BlobClient`, you must provide `container name` and `blob name`

Comment: Hope the syntax is good for code approach. Thanks.

Comment: I too got it:). Thanks.